# Knockout.js toggle style with undefined

Tags: knockout.js

I would like to toggle style based on observable property, which in the beginning doesn't exist. So it is undefined. But on click it becomes defined (a function), but the style doesn't change for some reason. I console.log VM, and the property appears there. The code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <script>
            function ViewModel_icon() {
                self2 = this;
                self2.tasks = ko.observableArray([
                    {
                        task: ko.observable("Task1"),
                        time: ko.observable("Saturday, 5 May 2018"),
                        status: ko.observable("active"),
                        priority: ko.observable("medium")
                    }
                ]);

                self2.checkUrgent = function (data){
                    if(data.urgent === undefined){
                        data.urgent = ko.observable('true');
                    }
                }
            }

            var VM1 = new ViewModel_icon();

            ko.applyBindings(VM1);
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="icon" data-bind='foreach: tasks'>
        <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle" data-bind='click: $parent.checkUrgent, style: {"color" : $data.urgent !== undefined? "red" : "black"}'></i>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you need to add observables after binding, then there is this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270902/adding-observable-properties-to-model-after-ko-applybindings-in-knockout-js  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I see that the property urgent represents a boolean; so instead of not defining it, it can be initialized with false, as there are only 2 valid values (true or false).

Have a look at the runnable refactor of your code below.

```js
function ViewModel_icon() {
    self2 = this;
    self2.tasks = ko.observableArray([
    {
        task: ko.observable("Task1"),
        time: ko.observable("Saturday, 5 May 2018"),
        status: ko.observable("active"),
        priority: ko.observable("medium"),
        urgent: ko.observable(false)
    }
    ]);

    self2.checkUrgent = function (data){
                
        if(!data.urgent()){
            data.urgent(true);
        }
    }
}

var VM1 = new ViewModel_icon();            
ko.applyBindings(VM1);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="icon" data-bind='foreach: tasks'>    
    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle" data-bind='click: $parent.checkUrgent, style: {"color" : $data.urgent() ? "red" : "black"}'></i>
</div>
```